# Expression to set Legend SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a report query that has "Year" as a parameter. If user selects 2016 in the parameter, the query produces 2016 values in a column named "SelectedYear", and 2015 values in a column called "PreviousYear".

I want the legend for the bar chart to then be 2016 and 2015 respectively. If I go Series Properties - Legend - Expression and I do =Parameters!Year.Value, THIS one gets 2016.

If I do =Parameters!Year.Value - 1 for the other one, the legend name remains the column name instead of 2015.

Comment: try convertig it to an int, your paramerter might be text

Comment: Thanks Allan Schofield but that does not work. I did =CInt(Parameters!Year.Value) - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the year selected in the parameter the expression takes the value of the parameter as it is and displays it as the legend text with no problem. !param - 1 gave issues.

SSRS wants the result to be a string but it comes as int. Thanks Alan Schofield for making me think about this. In this case the integer must be converted to string so the correct expression is:

```
=CStr(Parameters!Year.Value - 1)
```

This needs to be in the Series properties - Legend